# Angular 15 update - build time increase

Tags: angular

After updating to angular 15 from 14 we started experiencing a lot of build time issues.
Do you know if it could be linked to angular/material with legacy components migration or maybe changing to custom-webpack for the builder could be the issue? I'm kinda lost and I don't know how could I troubleshoot this build time increase.

Comment: Hi @Gonzalo Diaz Ailan: Did you find any solution to this issue of build time increased, I recently moved from angular 14 to 15, and build time increased drastically.

Comment: For us it was a problem with "@use" 'angular/material' in scss files to do some operations.
When I inspected the project with webpack-bundle-analyzer we realized scss files  HUMONGOUS, like 85% of all the bundle size.
We endend remplacing all "@use" 'angular/material' that we used for a single function for a custom function home-made for the case. (It is a really particular scenario where we used 'theming' from 'angular/material' to calculate some color palettes).
Recap: try to analyze with a bundle analyzer to spot the critical spot then maybe I could help a little bit more.